# Why am i getting ?? when i try to read ä character from a text file in java?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I am trying to read text from a text file. There are some special characters like å,ä and ö. When i make a string and print out that string then i get ?? from these special characters. I am using the following code:

```
File fileDir = new File("files/myfile.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));

String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    System.out.println("strLine: "+strLine);
}
```

Can anybody tell me whats the problem. I want strLine to show and save å, ä and ö as they are in text file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would happen if the file isn't actually UTF 8.

Comment: Make sure the file you are reading is actually encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: What is the content of the file ? Please write that content in question

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I made a single txt file and saved it as UTF-8 encoding. And in Eclipse i am using UTF-8 encoded console as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might not be with the file but with the console where you are trying to print. I suggest you follow the following steps

1. Make sure the file you are reading is encoded in UTF-8.
2. Make sure the console you are printing to has the proper encoding/charset to display these characters

Finally, this article [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) is a must read.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here for the lists of Java supported encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Most common single-byte encoding that includes non-ascii characters is ISO8859_1; maybe your file is that, and you should specifiy that encoding for your FileInputStream